# Install app using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, flash, air, adobe

I must install `.air` file using PowerShell script. Because of that, I converted to `.exe`, and tried running installation with PowerShell, but this not work.

Also I converted to .msi and that installation too has error.

This is my error :

> *"This is a problem with the windows installer package.
>
>   A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected."*

This is my script for msi:

```
Msiexec /a C:\Users\PC-MS\Downloads\vmaxstudios.msi
```

This is my script for exe:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Users\smilos\Downloads\Firefox Installer (1).exe -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait
```

1) I convert `.air` file to `.exe`,

2) I convert the `.exe` file to `.msi`.

3) Trying to install the `.msi` does not work.

Does anyone have an idea of how to install using `.air` file? Or solution for `.msi` installation?

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work" and show the errors you get.

Comment: When I run installation on .exe, doesn't install app, only the installation is started and is not installed. When I run installation on .msi I get error "this is a problem with the windows installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected".

Comment: Please edit this into your question. There may be something recorded in the Windows event logs, look there for anything relevant and post that as well.

Comment: @StoiljkovićMiloš how are you converting .air to .exe? It's possible you are not making a valid .exe for Windows OS.